# getting "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" error, but I haven't declared the method I'm calling from as static

Tags: java

When I try compile I'm getting the error:

> cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getId() from the type Doctor.

`Doctor` is a sub-class of `Staff`. I get the same error when I replace `Doctor` with `Staff` in the code. I understand that I can't substitute a super-class for a sub-class so that's why `Staff` wont work, but in my `Database` class, I haven't declared anything as static so I don't understand why or how it is static and why I'm getting that error.

This is my database class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Database
{
String id;

private ArrayList<Staff> staff;

/**
 * Construct an empty Database.
 */
public Database()
{
    staff = new ArrayList<Staff>();
}

/**
 * Add an item to the database.
 * @param theItem The item to be added.
 */
public void addStaff(Staff staffMember)
{
    staff.add(staffMember);
}

/**
 * Print a list of all currently stored items to the
 * text terminal.
 */
public void list()
{
    for(Staff s : staff) {
        s.print();
        System.out.println();   // empty line between items
    }
}

public void printStaff()
{
    for(Staff s : staff){


        id = Doctor.getId();//This is where I'm getting the error.


        if(true)
        {
            s.print();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Staff class.

```
public class Staff
{
    private String name;
    private int staffNumber;
    private String office;
    private String id;

/**
 * Initialise the fields of the item.
 * @param theName The name of this member of staff.
 * @param theStaffNumber The number of this member of staff.
 * @param theOffice The office of this member of staff.
 */
public Staff(String staffId, String theName, int theStaffNumber, String theOffice)
{
    id = staffId;
    name = theName;
    staffNumber = theStaffNumber;
    office = theOffice;
}

public String getId()
{
   return this.id;
}


/**
 * Print details about this member of staff to the text terminal.
 */
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("ID: " + id);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Staff Number: " + staffNumber);
    System.out.println("Office: " + office);

}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the source for `Doctor.getId()`? You are calling it as if it were `static`, is it static?

Comment: Reduce your code sample. Pretty much all of it is irrelevant. All that's needed is how the `getId()` method is defined and the line of code that won't compile. (You should of course test your reduced sample to see if the error still occurs in it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the method as if it's static, since you're calling it using the class name: `Doctor.getId()`.

You'll need an instance of the class `Doctor` to call the instance methods.

Perhaps you intend to call `getId` on the `s` (instance of Staff) in the loop?

Comment: I've called getId on the instance of staff in the loop and it worked. Thank you :) It now prints all of the staff (I've got two types of staff - doctors and nurses). What I'm trying to do is just print a selected type of staff but I think I can figure out the rest myself (I'm still pretty new to Java). I differentiate them by the first digit of their ID number.